# Syntax error When convert from MySQL to T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-convert

I'm new in SQL . 
I'm converting mysql to SQL.

I've found an error when I use DateAdd function.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT
      [id],
      [test_code],
      [test_name],
      [test_price],
      [discount],
      DATEADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL [test_duration] HOUR) as delivery_date,       
      [is_active]
    FROM [icddrb_tblab].[dbo].[tb_test]
    WHERE [icddrb_tblab].[dbo].[tb_test].[id] =0
```

It gives error:
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 7

> Incorrect syntax near 'test_duration'.'

Can anyone suggest me, where is the issue.

Comment: If you use SQLServer you can try `DATEADD(HOUR,[test_duration],GETDATE()) as delivery_date`.

Comment: "Microsoft SQL Server" is sometimes (frustratingly) referred to as just "SQL", but MS does NOT produce a product called "SQL". Please always refer to the MS produced database by "sql-server" in the tags. SQL is a language.

Answer (score 1):

`DATEADD` function takes parameter like this `DATEADD (datepart , number , date )`

You can use this.

```
SELECT
      [id],
      [test_code],
      [test_name],
      [test_price],
      [discount],
      DATEADD(HOUR, [test_duration], CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ) as delivery_date,       
      [is_active]
    FROM [icddrb_tblab].[dbo].[tb_test]
    WHERE [icddrb_tblab].[dbo].[tb_test].[id] =0
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
DATEADD(HOUR,[test_duration], CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) as delivery_date,
```

its the actual format.

Comment: hey, why you post the answer that is already here, instead of accepting the existing one?